# RSA sign a python dictionery containing bytes objects?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, cryptography

I have a python dictionary acting as a certificate which I want to RSA sign using `cryptography` Module The problem, is that I can't convert the `dictionary` object to a `bytes` object. The dictionary looks like:

```
ISSUER = b"RSA AUTHORITY"
SUBJECT = b"Domain.com"
SUBJECT_PUBLIC_KEY = rsa_public_key_bytes

all_data = {}
    all_data["SUBJECT"] = subject_name
    all_data["SUBJECT_PUBLIC_KEY"] = subject_public_key
    all_data["ISSUER"] = issuer_name
```

JSON refuses to accept an object containing bytes object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beacuse JSON format doen't support bytes, but only supports unicode strings,

you have to convert the values to Unicode using this `decode_dict` method:

```
import base64
import json

ISSUER = b"RSA AUTHORITY"
SUBJECT = b"Domain.com"
SUBJECT_PUBLIC_KEY = b'sabich'

all_data = {}
all_data["SUBJECT"] = SUBJECT
all_data["SUBJECT_PUBLIC_KEY"] = SUBJECT_PUBLIC_KEY
all_data["ISSUER"] = ISSUER


def decode_dict(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        d[k] = v.decode('utf-8')
    return d

all_data = decode_dict(all_data)

# {'SUBJECT': 'Domain.com', 'SUBJECT_PUBLIC_KEY': 'sabich', 'ISSUER': 'RSA AUTHORITY'}
x = json.dumps(all_data)

print(all_data)
```

Comment: You are encoding as base-64 then decoding bytes back as "ASCII" this will cause data corruption try with this example and you will see data is corrupted after being decoded.